# Is it within WordPress guidelines to update another plugin's database fields from my own plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

Is it within the WordPress guidelines and acceptable practices to modify the database fields of another plugin, specifically the meta description fields, from my own plugin?

I would like to check if either Yoast SEO or All in One SEO is enabled and generate a meta description, updating the corresponding fields in the database.

I can technically do this but my concern is whether or not this is an acceptable practice and dont violates WordPress policy.

Comment: There's nothing official, so this is really just a matter of opinion and this site is not suited to opinion based questions. That being said 3rd-party extensions for other plugins are very common and perfectly acceptable, as long as it's clear what you're doing and you use the plugins' APIs correctly, if they have them.

Comment: are you trying to do this in a plugin that will end up in the wordpress.org plugin repository? If it's just for your or a client go wild, otherwise keep in mind you need to be able to mark an answer as the factually correct answer, not just the most reassuring or best written

Comment: Yes, it will end up in the official WP repository.

Comment: I suggest you try and ask WordPress directly, and if you can get an answer please post it here too

Answer (score 1):

WordPress guidelines doesn’t restrict doing this. In fact, modifying database directly is no different from doing update_post_meta() or update_option() which are used widely everywhere.

However, modifying data of other plugins need to be done carefully because the data might be referred somewhere else.

I’d recommend using the plugins’ hooks to get/change the data instead of modifying it directly.